# Oracle-How to check if max_string_size is standard or extended

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am new on Oracle and maybe my question is an easiest one however I could not find my answer. I want to check max_string_size. Is there any useful system query ? 
Kind regards,
Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In SQL*Plus, or an environment that imitates SQL*Plus, run this command:

```
show parameter max_string_size
```

The value could be STANDARD or EXTENDED.
You could find some useful information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321).

Comment: Thank you very much! It is what I need. For being a toad user I run the query with F5 instead of F9 and it works fine.

Answer (score 24):

If you need to find the results via a query you could use....

```
SELECT name, value
  FROM v$parameter
 WHERE name = 'max_string_size'
```

Comment: You're awesome.  May use this query in my open source C# project, FluentMigrator.